# Can someone tell me how to include files with multi-project templates for dot net core?

Tags: c#, .net-core

My open source project DataTier.Net (https://github.com/DataJuggler/DataTier.Net) is in the process of being upgraded to work with DotNetCore.

Everything works after I updated my Nuget packages, but when I got to the point of updating the multiple project template that is installed into Visual Studio, all the folders are created but none of the files are included.

I admit I copied my .vstemplate files from my .NetFramework project templates since I do not even see 'Export Template' as a menu option for DotNetCore.

I do realize projects include all files in dotnetcore, but the replace parameters for the namespaces for the files I do need has to occur so I am stuck.

Here is one of the .vstemplate files:

```xml
<VSTemplate Version="3.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005" Type="Project">
  <TemplateData>
    <Name>DataGateway</Name>
    <Description>Create a new DataGateway which is part of a DataTier.Net.Core class library.</Description>
    <ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType>
    <ProjectSubType>
    </ProjectSubType>
    <SortOrder>1000</SortOrder>
    <CreateNewFolder>true</CreateNewFolder>
    <DefaultName>DataGateway</DefaultName>
    <ProvideDefaultName>true</ProvideDefaultName>
    <LocationField>Enabled</LocationField>
    <EnableLocationBrowseButton>true</EnableLocationBrowseButton>
    <Icon>__TemplateIcon.ico</Icon>
  </TemplateData>
  <TemplateContent>
    <Project TargetFileName="DataGateway.csproj" File="DataGateway.csproj" ReplaceParameters="true">
      <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="Gateway.cs">Gateway.cs</ProjectItem>
      <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="ListHelper.cs">ListHelper.cs</ProjectItem>
    </Project>
  </TemplateContent>
</VSTemplate>
```

Have templates completely changed for dot net core? I searched Google and couldn't find an answer.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with VS Templates but i found this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-multi-project-templates?view=vs-2019

Comment: That is for the Dot Net Framework, and that is how my project currently works.

Thanks for trying to answer.

I googled some more when I woke up and found this for dot net core:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/cli-templates-create-project-template

Answer (score 1):

Templates have totally changed, which is probably for the best as the old way was a pain, but at least it was a pain I knew how to do.

The good news is now they use Nuget packages, so that is easier for everyone:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/cli-templates-create-project-template

This uses a command line, which I would rather have a GUI, but if it works it works.

I will post an update on my progress learning how to use the new templates as soon as I can.